# SVN: automatically running something every time the repository is updated

Tags: svn, automation, tortoisesvn

Would like to automatically run a script every time I update my local repository from the SVN server. Any ideas how this can be accomlished?

I use tortoise svn on windows, others in my team use other SVN tools on a mac.

Thanks

Gidi

Comment: The local part is called the [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc), not [repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.repository.html).

Answer (score 3):

Look at the ["post-update" hook](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html) in TortoiseSVN's documentation. If the other team members use the command-line utilities, they can wrap the `svn update` call into some shell script that performs the post-update action as well.